# Run iteratively rows by rows in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

i have a question related to data table in R.
For example, i have a data like this

```
a=data.table(c=(1:10),d=(2:11))
a[1,e:=1]

    c  d  e
1:  1  2  1
2:  2  3 NA
3:  3  4 NA
4:  4  5 NA
5:  5  6 NA
6:  6  7 NA
7:  7  8 NA
8:  8  9 NA
9:  9 10 NA
10: 10 11 NA
```

Now, i want to calculate the value of e, row by row, with the value of e equal (c+d) multiple with e of previous row. So data table must update row by row here.
i don't want to run a for loop here because it takes a long time. Any of you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Like this?

```
a[-1, e := c + d]
a[, e := cumprod(e)]
#     c  d          e
# 1:  1  2          1
# 2:  2  3          5
# 3:  3  4         35
# 4:  4  5        315
# 5:  5  6       3465
# 6:  6  7      45045
# 7:  7  8     675675
# 8:  8  9   11486475
# 9:  9 10  218243025
#10: 10 11 4583103525
```

**Edit:**

Here is a solution using `by`. However, that won't be faster than a well written `for` loop (e.g., using `set`).

```
a[1, f := 1]
a[, f := if (.GRP == 1) f
  else (c + d) * a[.GRP - 1, f] , by = seq_len(nrow(a))]
```

Here a solution with `set`:

```
a[1, g := 1]
for (i in 2 : nrow(a)) set(a, i, "g", a[(i), c + d] * a[(i - 1), g])
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm looking for a more general solution when we have to update rows by rows. this solution can solve this specific problems but if we have to deal with other calculations then it will not be solved

Comment: @ThanhQuang Iterating over the rows of a data.table is not a good idea. Regardless how you do it (`for` loop or using data.table's `by`) it will always be slow. You should look for a vectorized solution to your specific problem as I've shown here. If everything else fails you can always turn to Rcpp.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. my specific problems are very complicated, but can you show me how can i do it with by?

Comment: Alternately, I guess `a$f[.GRP - 1L]` for less overhead.